# Why is my computed value returning an empty string when it has a valid ID in the console? - Nuxt 3 with useLazyFetch() and reactive queryParameter

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I try to use useLazyFetch() in Nuxt 3 with reactive queryParameter. This parameter lose reactivity and my requests fail.

I create my own composable

```js
import { useLazyFetch } from 'nuxt/app'
import { useUserManagerStore } from '~/stores/userManagerStore'

type useFetchType = typeof useLazyFetch

export const useAPILazyFetch: useFetchType = (path, options = {}) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()
  const userManagerStore = useUserManagerStore()
  options.baseURL = config.public.baseURL
  options.headers = [
    ['Authorization', 'Bearer ' + (userManagerStore.user?.access_token || '')]
  ]
  return useLazyFetch(path, options)
}
```

So here i get user

```js
const { data: userInfo, pending: pendingUser } = await useAPILazyFetch<IUser>(
  ApiEndpoints.GET_USER_BY_ID,
  { query: { contactId } }
             ^^^^^^^^^  - this is ref from props
)
```

In user I have headId and i need it to get head of current user.
I create `computed` to get id of head

```js
const computedHead1Id = computed(() => {
  return useUnProxy(userInfo)?.head1Id || ''
})
```

And then I try to get head:

```js
const {
  data: head1Info,
  pending: pendingHead1Info,
  error: head1InfoError
} = await useAPILazyFetch<IUser>(() => ApiEndpoints.GET_USER_BY_ID, {
  immediate: false,
  watch: [computedHead1Id],
  query: { contactId: computedHead1Id.value }
})
```

But `computedHead1Id` always `''` here! I check in console and there is a valid Id.
And I have error because my id is `''`, but actually it not truth.

What I'am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after few hours I found a problem.

This is working good:

```js
const {
  data: head1Photo,
  pending: pendingHead1Photo,
  error: head1PhotoError
} = await useAPILazyFetch(ApiEndpoints.GET_USER_PHOTO, {
  immediate: false,
  query: { contactId: computedHead1Id }
})
```

Here we need only query with ref inside, without unwrapping `.value`